# VB.NET printing report without using report button

Tags: vb.net, report

So I have this code:

```
    Dim d As DateTime = Now ' Define d as Date and time for formatted date
    Dim ds As New Recipt 'Define the dataset
    Dim sReportDataSource1 As ReportDataSource ' Define data source

    ReportViewer1.Reset() ' Reset report viewer
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "aClub.Recipt.rdlc" ' Load report
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear() 'Clear report
    sReportDataSource1 = New ReportDataSource() 'Set report data source
    ds.recipt_MAIN.Rows.Add(Label6.Text, "trans", TextBox2.Text,
                            TimeOfDay.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"), d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))

    sReportDataSource1.Name = "DataSet1" ' Name the data set
    sReportDataSource1.Value = ds.recipt_MAIN ' Give it the value

    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(sReportDataSource1) ' Add to reportviewer

    'rv.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
    ReportViewer1.RefreshReport() 'Refresh report
```

Basically what I want to do is print automatically (like after the ReportViewer1.RefreshReport() function. I have tried http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms252091%28v=vs.110%29.aspx but it messes up the report format big time.

What else can I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved, I have exported to PDF instead and then printed it.